Help with Q-learning Using Dynamic Learning Rate with RMSprop:
I'm implementing Q-learning with a dynamic learning rate inspired by RMSprop, following an approach I found in an article. The goal is for the learning rate to adjust over time based on the magnitude of the temporal difference (TD) error. However, I'm encountering an issue where the gradient seems to increase over time, when it ideally should decrease as the agent learns more about the environment.
Specifically:
I expect the gradient (TD error) to reduce gradually as the Q-values converge, but instead, it seems to grow.
Consequently, my learning rate, which starts at 0.001, does not increase over time as expected, remaining lower than anticipated or even decreasing.
Here’s the Q-learning update function I’m using:
python
Copy code
def update_q_table(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
"""Update Q-table using the Q-learning update rule."""
best_next_action = np.argmax(self.q_table[next_state, :])
current_q = self.q_table[state, action]
next_q = self.q_table[next_state, best_next_action]
# Calculate TD error
td_error = reward + self.discount_factor * next_q - current_q

# Update gradient cache using RMSprop approach
self.gradient_cache[state, action] = 0.9 * self.gradient_cache[state, action] + (1 - 0.9) * np.abs(td_error**2)

# Calculate adjusted Q-value with dynamic learning rate
updated_q = current_q + self.learning_rate * td_error / np.sqrt(self.gradient_cache[state, action] + 1e-8)

# Update Q-table
self.q_table[state, action] = updated_q

